# Textures and materials to show up while playing animation in 3d viewport

Tags: animation, texturing, 3d-view

I am trying to get my textures and materials to show up in the 3d viewport while playing the animation of my scene. The textures and materials are showing in my 3d viewport. However, when i play the animation the objects do not move until i stop the animation.

Right now i have my `method to display objects in the 3d view` set to `rendered`. If i have it set to anything else, the textures and materials go away and i only see the blank objects, but they will move with the animation.

**How can i get the objects to properly animate in the 3d viewport with textures and materials applied?**

---

Clarification:

I press `alt+A` to run the animation. The animation plays, but none of my objects move like they are supposed to. Then i press `alt+A` and the objects jump to the location they are supposed to be at the frame where the animation stopped. I want the animations to move like they are supposed to while the animation is playing. I can stop through the animation using the timeline by pressing `left or right arrow` and the objects move. But i want this to work while playing the animation.

Thanks

Comment: @MrZak Added clarification.

Comment: Do you mean animated texures (as in an image sequence or a video file used as texture?)

Comment: @cegaton I have a plane that moves from left to right that has a material and texture applied to the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the viewport in render view mode, sluggish animation and freezing are not uncommon when you try to play your animation. Try setting the viewport render mode to "material" or "textured" and you should be able to play animations smoothly with your textures/materials visible and animated.

This has one caveat however, the Blender Internal render engine does not support procedural texure in material view mode, and will display the object incorrectly.

Comment: I have already tried that, i mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Ah right I see that now. My mistake.

Comment: no problem, easy mistake

Comment: I've done some searching. It appears that Blender Internal does not support procedural textures in the viewport. If I create a material and give it a texture however, it shows up and animates correctly in material view. As soon as I mix in a procedural texure however, the material breaks in the viewport.